# Использование java-google-translate-text-to-speech на android

Tags: java, android, google-translate

Возникла необходимость переводить введенный пользователем текст с русского на  английский, покопавшись в интернете, решил использовать [вот это](https://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/), но сразу же возникла проблема. Вот этот код:

```
Thread one = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
            String text = translate.translate("I am programmer", Language.ENGLISH, Language.PORTUGUESE);
            Log.d("TEXT: ",text);
        } catch(Exception v) {
            Log.d("ERR: ", v.toString());
        }
    }
};
one.start();
```

Вылетает с ошибкой:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=I%20am%20programmer&hl=en&sl=en&tl=pt&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1
```

Код скопирован со странички переводчика, не понимаю, почему не работает.

Comment: разрешение на интернет?

Comment: В манифесте <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1):

Приведенная библиотека использует устаревший `API`, который больше не работает.
Ссылка на API недоступна: http://translate.google.com/translate_a/
Вам придется поискать другой способ.